# Issue in progressbar in onBindViewHolder method

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have used third party lib for progress bar ,everything works fine but in **onBindViewHolder** method when i write  **holder.donutprogress.setFinishedStrokeColor(colorsdark[progresspoint])**

same color repeat for every item , when i see logs colors are different but only second position color is repeating in progressbar

```
public class RatingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RatingAdapter.ViewHolderRating> {


    ArrayList<RatingResp> ratingModalList;
    public Activity mActivity;

    int colorsdark[]={R.color.progress_one_dark,R.color.progress_two_dark,R.color.progress_three_dark
    ,R.color.progress_four_dark};

    int colorslight[]={R.color.progress_one_light,R.color.progress_two_light,R.color.progress_three_light
            ,R.color.progress_four_light};

    int progresspoint=0;


    class ViewHolderRating extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @Nullable
        @BindView(R.id.item_progress_rate)
        DonutProgress donutprogress;
        public ViewHolderRating(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }

    public RatingAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<RatingResp> items) {
        this.ratingModalList = items;
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolderRating onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
         View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_rating_raw, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolderRating(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderRating holder, int position) {
        configureViewHolderRating( holder, position);
    }

    private void configureViewHolderRating(RatingAdapter.ViewHolderRating holder, int position) {
        if (progresspoint==4){
            progresspoint=0;
        }
        Log.e("Progress color ",": "+colorsdark[progresspoint]);
        RatingResp ratingResp = ratingModalList.get(position);
        holder.donutprogress.setFinishedStrokeColor(colorsdark[progresspoint]);
        holder.donutprogress.setUnfinishedStrokeColor(colorslight[progresspoint]);
        holder.donutprogress.setInnerBottomTextColor(colorsdark[progresspoint]);
        holder.donutprogress.setTextColor(colorsdark[progresspoint]);
        progresspoint=progresspoint+1;
        holder.donutprogress.setSuffixText(" ");
        holder.donutprogress.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(ratingResp.getRating()));

    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return ratingModalList.size();
    }
}
```

This is how i attached data to my recycle view

```
 LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        ratingAdapter = new RatingAdapter(getActivity(),ratingModalArrayList);
        recrating.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recrating.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recrating.setAdapter(ratingAdapter);
```

Comment: please don't use butter knife because it's sometime not bind your actual layout when you have same id of view in other layouts in xml!!

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ Yes bro ,but i tried with out butterknief also but only in adapter class  and same issue repeat,should i remove injection from my fragment class also?

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ nope not working same issue ,i don't know  why  but holder.donutprogress.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(ratingResp.getRating())); i can see correct data for this method but only background color thing is not working

Comment: ok .it's working ?? @Raj

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ nope brother it is not

Comment: try to change in xml one time if it is working than you need to go through .java

Answer (score 0):

So Basically i don't know how its working but i just added

```
  int colorcodedark = ContextCompat.getColor(mActivity, colorsdark[progresspoint]);
  int colorcodelight = ContextCompat.getColor(mActivity,colorslight[progresspoint]);
```

and its working now just have to change method configureViewHolderRating to below code

```
    private void configureViewHolderRating(RatingAdapter.ViewHolderRating holder, int position) {
    RatingResp ratingResp = ratingModalList.get(position);
    if (progresspoint==4){
        progresspoint=0;
    }else{

    }
    int colorcodedark = ContextCompat.getColor(mActivity, colorsdark[progresspoint]);
    int colorcodelight = ContextCompat.getColor(mActivity,colorslight[progresspoint]);
    holder.donutprogress.setFinishedStrokeColor(colorcodedark);
    holder.donutprogress.setUnfinishedStrokeColor(colorcodelight);
    holder.donutprogress.setInnerBottomTextColor(colorcodedark);
    holder.donutprogress.setTextColor(colorcodedark);
    progresspoint=progresspoint+1;
    holder.donutprogress.setSuffixText(" ");  
holder.donutprogress.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(ratingResp.getRating()));

}
```

its great if anyyone can help me about how its starting to work by adding two variable inside method